# Offset 0 is invalid for MySQL result index 10 , cannot retrieve data from mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, json

In the script, no matter I input a right or a wrong user name, the result remains the same.

It is like this:

{"success":1,"message":"Login successfully!","user":{"customerID":null,"firstname":null,"lastname":null,"address":null,"postcode":null,"phone":null}}

I tried to use mysql_data_seek() and it returns Offset 0 is invalid for MySQL result index 10.

I guess there is nothing fetched by mysql_query().

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
 <?PHP

$username = "";
$password = "";
$re = array();


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$username = htmlspecialchars($username);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);

//==========================================
//  CONNECT TO THE LOCAL DATABASE
//==========================================
$dbusername = ""; 
    $dbpassword = ""; 
    $host = ""; 
    $dbname = "";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($dbname, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

    $username = quote_smart($username, $db_handle);
    $password = quote_smart($password, $db_handle);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE username = $username AND password = md5($password)";
    $info = mysql_query($query);

//====================================================
//  CHECK TO SEE IF THE $result VARIABLE IS TRUE
//====================================================

    if ($info) {
$user = mysql_fetch_array( $info );
echo $user['firstname'];
    $re["success"]=1;
    $re["message"] = "Login successfully!";
//add parameters that will return to android
    $re["user"]["customerID"]=$user['customerID'];
    $re["user"]["firstname"]=$user['firstname'];
    $re["user"]["lastname"] = $user['lastname'];
    $re["user"]["address"]=$user['address'];
    $re["user"]["postcode"]=$user['postcode'];
    $re["user"]["phone"]=$user['phone'];

    $re= json_encode($re);
    echo $re;

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
        $_SESSION["re"]=$re;
        //header ("Location: userdata.php");

    }
    else {
    $re["success"]=0;
    $re["message"] = "User Not Found";
    $re = json_encode($re);
    echo $re;
    }
}

else {
    $re["success"]=0;
    $re["message"] = "Can not connect to database";
    $re= json_encode($re);
    echo $re;
}

}


?>


<html>
<head>
<title>Basic Login Script</title>
</head>
<body>

<FORM NAME ="Customer Login" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="login.php">

Username: <INPUT TYPE = 'TEXT' Name ='username'  value="<?PHP print $username;?>"     maxlength="45">
Password: <INPUT TYPE = 'TEXT' Name ='password'  value="<?PHP print $password;?>"  maxlength="45">

<P align = center>
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit"  VALUE = "Login">
</P>

</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, added rows count check `mysql_num_rows($info);`

```
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".md5($password)."' ";

        $info = mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error()); 

        $count = mysql_num_rows($info); // added rows count check

        if($count>0){       

             $user = mysql_fetch_array( $info );
            echo $user['firstname'];
            $re["success"]=1;
            $re["message"] = "Login successfully!";
            //add parameters that will return to android
            $re["user"]["customerID"]=$user['customerID'];
            $re["user"]["firstname"]=$user['firstname'];
            $re["user"]["lastname"] = $user['lastname'];
            $re["user"]["address"]=$user['address'];
            $re["user"]["postcode"]=$user['postcode'];
            $re["user"]["phone"]=$user['phone'];    
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
            $_SESSION["re"]=$re;
            //header ("Location: userdata.php");
            $re= json_encode($re);
            echo $re;

        }
        else {
            $re["success"]=0;
            $re["message"] = "User Not Found";
            $re = json_encode($re);
            echo $re;
        }
```

Note: Use mysqli_* function instead of mysql_* functions (deprecated)

Comment: I added mysql_num_rows($info); and the result becomes {"success":0,"message":"User Not Found"} no matter what's the input.  mysql_query() returns nothing to me. How can I fix this?

Comment: echo $query string and run in mysql query window to check whether table customer has data

Comment: $info = mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());  update me the error

Comment: Sure, it has data. I've double checked that.

Comment: I add $info = mysql_query($query) or die("MySQL ERROR: ".mysql_error());  But nothing changes. Still {"success":0,"message":"User Not Found"}

Comment: no error from query...?? what is your count value that is echo $count = mysql_num_rows($info);

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `if` any row returns or not.

also `session_start()` must be at the top of file

```
session_start();
$query = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE username = $username AND password = md5($password) LIMIT 1";
$info = mysql_query($query);
$found = mysql_num_rows($info);

if($found!=0)
{
    $user = mysql_fetch_array( $info );
    echo $user['firstname'];
    $re["success"]=1;
    $re["message"] = "Login successfully!";
    //add parameters that will return to android
    $re["user"]["customerID"]=$user['customerID'];
    $re["user"]["firstname"]=$user['firstname'];
    $re["user"]["lastname"] = $user['lastname'];
    $re["user"]["address"]=$user['address'];
    $re["user"]["postcode"]=$user['postcode'];
    $re["user"]["phone"]=$user['phone'];

    $re= json_encode($re);
    echo $re;

    $_SESSION['login'] = "1";
    $_SESSION["re"]=$re;
    //header ("Location: userdata.php");
}
```

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. move on `mysqli_*` functions asap

Comment: I added mysql_num_rows($info); and the result becomes {"success":0,"message":"User Not Found"} no matter what's the input. mysql_query() returns nothing to me. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

if the result set is empty `mysql_data_seek()` will fail with a `E_WARNING`. That is I think happening in you case because you are not checking whether the result set is empty or not before calling the `mysql_data_seek()`.

Always check the result for number of rows if they are >=1 then you are safe to call `mysql_data_seek()`